# Routing Post to a non standard uri web api

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I´m writing a REST web api and I need to have an endpoint like **/api/users/{id}/modify** or **http://localhost:8080/api/users/6/modify** using a POST method.

I have a UsersController class with al read/write actions but I´m only able to access the post method by accessing /api/users, not /api/users/6/modify. I need to expand the hierarchy(if that is well said).

How can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) of asp.net web api.

The first thing is to enable it over the `HttpConfiguration`, in asp.net web api template, you can see it on the `WebApiConfig.cs` file.

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApplication
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            // Other Web API configuration not shown...
        }
    }
}
```

After that you can define a controller which should inherits from `ApiController` and you can use the `Route` attribute to define a custom route, for sample:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/users")]
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{id}/modify")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostModify(int id) 
    { 
       // code ...
    }
}
```

The `RoutePrefix` will define a prefix for all actions on the controller. So, to access the `PostModify` you should use a route like `/api/users/6/modify` in a `post` action. If you do not want it, just remove the `RoutePrefix` and define the complete url on the route attribute, like this: `/api/users/{id}/modify`.

You also can guarantee the type of the `id` argument defining a route like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/users")]
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{id:int}/modify")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostModify(int id) 
    { 
       // code ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man!!.. That was exactly what I was looking for. It worked just fine. I´ve tried other things before this and I wasn´t able to make it work. Thanks again.